# css for centering the div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display my div tag in center of the screen.I draw my screen as black color ,current display position of div tag in red color(which I unexpected) and my preferd location of div tag in green color.[image]

```css
 .welcome{
 margin-left:20%
  font-size: 10px;
   border:1px solid #6AA121;
    width :60%;
    height:100px;
   background-color:#C3FDB8;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="welcome">
   </div>
```

I want to display in middle.

Comment: Remove `position:absolute` and add `margin:0 auto`

Comment: @HamedAliKhan This removes much of the utility of `position: absolute` - you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

## NOTICE

---

After going over your code again, it's become apparent that you are missing the `;` after your margin left, and so the browser is ignoring it (hence why your code isn't working). However, you might find it a better alternative to use the `left, right, top and bottom` properties instead:

[image]

---

## My Approach

---

since you are using `position: absolute;`, and you've given your div a width of 60%, you can use:

```
left:20%;
```

Since your width is 60%; leaving 40% of screen available.

```
40/2 (left and right gap) = 20% either side
```

Leaving:

```css
.welcome {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #6AA121;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C3FDB8;
  position: absolute;
  left:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use transform:translateX

With the use of absolute positioning, the most flexible approach would be to offset the right hand edge of the div by 50% of the parent width, then by 50% of its own width using the **transform** property, **`translateX`**

The advantage is you dont need to rely on specifying absolute width/offset values in, e.g. `px`, so the `div` will remain centered if its dimensions change.

Additionally- for positioning; top/right/bottom/left should be used where possible in place of any margin or padding values, this approach also follows this.

```css
.welcome {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #6AA121;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C3FDB8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* <--- move div right by 50% of parent width */
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* <--- move div left by 50% of its own width */
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome">
</div>
```

**`translateX`** is well supported, see [here for a full rundown](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate), the main point to note is that transforms require the `-ms-` prefix in IE9.and you will need `-webkit-` for iOS/Safari.

Comment: Elegant and for me the best answer here.

Comment: @SW4: You might want to include prefixes for the Translate ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.welcome{
 margin-left:20%
  font-size: 10px;
   border:1px solid #6AA121;
    width :60%;
    height:100px;
   background-color:#C3FDB8;
    position: relative; /* change absolute to relative */
  margin : auto; /* & set margin to auto*/
 }
```

```html
<div class="welcome">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh8LL7up/)**

If absolute position is not needed, then use like this:
 CSS:

```
.welcome {
    font-size: 10px;
    border:1px solid #6AA121;
    width :60%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#C3FDB8;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you need Position:absolute, then use like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh8LL7up/1/)**

```
.welcome {
    font-size: 10px;
    border:1px solid #6AA121;
    width :60%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#C3FDB8;
    position: absolute;
    left:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width and then set the margins to auto. E.g.:

```
.welcome {width:60%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Setting both the left and right margin to auto (as the above does) will center your div. If you do this without setting a width, the div will still be centered, but will fill the screen (or the previous div, at least) so you won't be able to tell.

Using `position:absolute` isn't a great idea here unless you need it for something else which isn't apparent in the question.

Comment: This won't work since position is set to absolute (which is fine to use btw)

Comment: Just spotted that - suggested that they don't use absolute unless it's necessary elsewhere; I suspect it was just an early attempt to center the div. If the OP uses *just* my code, which doesn't include the absolute, it will work. But good spot.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left` doesn't work properly with `position: absolute` (at least not in the way you are using it).

What you should write is this:

```
width: 60%;
left: 20%; // notice how this isn't margin-left
position: absolute;
```

This will centre the div.

If your div has a fixed width (e.g. `500px`), try this:

```
width: 500px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
position: absolute;
```

This works, and is the "correct" way of using `margin-left` with `position: absolute`.

Comment: I do believe margin-left works fine with absolutely positioned divs.

Comment: @jbutler483 no, it works fine, but the margin doesn't actually "push" the element (it just adds spacing)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try an easier way. Try to remove absolute positioning and set margin left and margin right on auto. Like in the example below.

```
.welcome {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  border:1px solid #6AA121;
  width :60%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#C3FDB8;
 }
```